# Bat file to call A.bat if time is less than 19:45 and to call B.bat if time is greater than 19:45

Tags: batch-file

Bat file to call A.bat if time  is less than 19:45 and to call B.bat if time is greater than 19:45
(i can not use windows task scheduler in this case because i have setting which makes my download manager to trigger this parent bat file each time a file is downloaded through this download manager)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following code as a baseline (you can use `bat` files but I prefer `cmd` as an extension):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set tm=%time%
:: Test data on lines below.
:: set tm=18:59:59.00
:: set tm=19:00:00.00
:: set tm=19:44:59.00
:: set tm=19:45:00.00
:: set tm=23:59:59.99
set hh=!tm:~0,2!
set mm=!tm:~3,2!
if !hh! lss 19 (
    call a.cmd
    goto :done
)
if !hh! equ 19 (
    if !mm! lss 45 (
        call a.cmd
        goto :done
    )
)
call b.cmd
:done
endlocal
```

Keep in mind that `%time%` is the same format as you get from the `time` command and this may depend on locale. The format I'm getting is `20:17:28.48` for around 8:15pm but your result may be different.

If it is, just adjust the substrings when setting `hh` and `mm`. The command:

```
set mm=!tm:~3,2!
```

sets `mm` to the two characters of `tm` at offset 3 (where offset 0 is the first character).

---

If you're not a big fan of spaghetti code, even in batch, you could also use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set tm=%time%
:: Test data on lines below.
:: set tm=18:59:59.00
:: set tm=19:00:00.00
:: set tm=19:44:59.00
:: set tm=19:45:00.00
:: set tm=23:59:59.99
set hh=!tm:~0,2!
set mm=!tm:~3,2!
if !hh! lss 19 (
    call a.cmd
) else (
    if !hh! equ 19 if !mm! lss 45 (
        call a.cmd
    ) else (
        call b.cmd
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Just curious: is there no 'else' in the Windows batch language?

Comment: Is there no 'or' in the Windows batch language? :)

Comment: @Adriano, it's not the most adaptable of languages but you _can_ do some things: `else` and `and` are shown. I usually emulate `or` with multiple `if`s setting a flag then an `if` based on that flag. Primitive but, if the only tool you have is the jaw of a mammoth, you can't be too fussy :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm just spoiled by the *sh languages.

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo. I was away from my computer i just tried your suggestion. it is working fine, fulfilling my all expectations. I appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: The jaw of the mammoth analogy is a nice one :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [DATE and TIME](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php) commands here.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently doing something similar and my solution was a for loop - not amazingly compact but got the job done:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:,. " %%i in ("%time%") do (

echo Timegrab = %%i %%j %%k %%l
set hr=%%i
set mn=%%j
set sc=%%k
set ms=%%l

)
```

Then all you would need to do is an IF statement to check whether %hr% was less than 19 and %mn% was less than 45.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: i can not use windows task sheduler in this case because i have setting which makes my download manager to trigger this parent bat file each time a file is downloaded through this download manager